# How can I limit choices to django ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django

How can I limit the number of choices to django ManyToManyField ? In my situation this is needed to choose one from many pick-up points:

`pickup = models.ManyToManyField(PickUpPoint,related_name='orders')`

How could I do another choice system?

Comment: If there is only a single option, then you use a `ForeignKey`, instead of a `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: Or you could use a `OnetoOneField`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can select a *single* `PickUpPoint`, then this is not a `ManyToManyField`, but a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). In a `ForeignKey`, you link to a *single* `PickUpPoint`:

```
pickup = models.ForeignKey(
    PickUpPoint,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    related_name='orders'
)
```

in case each order needs to select a *different* `PickUpPoint`, then you can use a [**`OneToOneField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField), which is in essence a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`.